# Itzykson & Zuber: Conjugate momentum sign

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, metric-tensor, hamiltonian-formalism, conventions

I can't give myself peace on a confusion about the signs. I'm studying on Claude Itzykson & Jean-Bernard Zuber, *Quantum Field Theory,* Dover Publications.
Metric convention $g_{\mu\nu}=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$. 
Page 108 formula 3-9, the conjugate momentum $\pi$ is given by:
$$\pi=\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\partial_{0}\varphi)}=\partial_{0}\varphi. \tag{3.9}$$
Considering that:
$$\partial_{\mu}=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right),$$ and 
$$k_{\mu} = (\omega_k,-k^1,-k^2,-k^3),$$
$$x^{\mu} = (t,x^1,x^2,x^3),$$
$$k \cdot x= k_{\mu}x^{\mu}=\omega_k t -k^1x^1-k^2x^2-k^3x^3,$$
$$\varphi(\textbf{x}) = \int d\widetilde{k}\left(a(k) e^{i\bf{k\cdot  x}} + a(k)^\dagger e^{-i\bf{k\cdot  x}}\right). \tag{3.37a}$$
I would expect
$$\pi(\textbf{x}) = ~ \color{red}{+} i \int d\widetilde{k} \, \omega_k \left(a(k) e^{i\bf{k\cdot x}} - a(k)^\dagger e^{-i\bf{k\cdot  x}}\right). $$
Page 115 formula 3-37b I find:
$$\pi(\textbf{x}) = \color{red}{-} i \int d\widetilde{k} \, \omega_k \left(a(k) e^{i\bf{k\cdot x}} - a(k)^\dagger e^{-i\bf{k\cdot  x}}\right) \tag{3.37b}$$
It's certainly my fault but I can't understand where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that in eq. (3.37) the time is set to zero $t=0$ and that the boldface denotes a 3-vector, not a 4-vector. Consider further down in I&Z's text:
$$ \varphi(\textbf{x},t) ~=~ \int d\widetilde{k}\left[a(k) e^{-ik\cdot  x} + a(k)^\dagger e^{ik\cdot  x}\right]. \tag{3.42}$$
Eq. (3.37b) follows with the correct sign from eqs. (3.9) & (3.42).